# keep first 2 words and the last word from a sentence

Tags: java, regex

i want to keep the first 2 words and the last word from a sentence, including the question mark at the end of the sentence.

> wie ging er ook alweer allemaal mee wat drinken in Utrecht?

should turn into

It should also work when the sentence is 3 words long.
So

> wie ging Utrecht?

should stay the same

No matter what i try, i find a few letters or nothing, could someone give a helping hand?
I have a good book about regex but i don't have time untill summer :(

Comment: Why not show us what you've tried? :)

Comment: Define "word" and "sentence".

Comment: again, this is **not** something that a regex is appropriate for, regular string manipulation methods will get you much better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not an appropriate place to use regular expressions.**

The correct way to do this in Java is to use the [`BreakIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) to detect "Words" and process them according to your logic. Just splitting on a character might not be semantically correct in all languages either.

Print first element:

```
 public static void printFirst(BreakIterator boundary, String source) {
     int start = boundary.first();
     int end = boundary.next();
     System.out.println(source.substring(start,end));
 }
```

Print last element:

```
 public static void printLast(BreakIterator boundary, String source) {
     int end = boundary.last();
     int start = boundary.previous();
     System.out.println(source.substring(start,end));
 }
```

Print the element at a specified position:

```
 public static void printAt(BreakIterator boundary, int pos, String source) {
     int end = boundary.following(pos);
     int start = boundary.previous();
     System.out.println(source.substring(start,end));
 }
```

Comment: cool really pro.
I must remember this for future projects :)
I build a textAnalyser once and this should have been good in it.
O yeah does BreakIterator use a regex and if not what makes it so good?

Comment: I would say, look at the source on how it works, but it is more aware of locale and unicode than a "dumb" regex.

Answer (score 4):

Try this ... uses [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String s = "wie ging er ook alweer allemaal mee wat drinken in Utrecht?";
String words[] = s.split(" ");
String firstTwo = words[0] + "  " + words[1]; // first two words
String lastOne = words[words.length - 1]; // last one
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex solution

```
^((?:\w+\s+){2}).*?(\S+)$
```

and replace with `$1$2`

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30d57)

Answer (score 0):

Just split on spaces and take the first two/last one, stripping punctuation as necessary from the first two words, and making sure of length. No point in using regex.